# Link in NextJs appends to current path but want to replace

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Let's say the current url looks like this: `localhost:3000/foo/hello` and hello being a dynamic route.
I have a Link Component with `href={'/something/test'}` and when clicking it I want to get to: `localhost:3000/something/test`, with test being a dynamic route.

But Clicking on that Link gets me to `localhost:3000/foo/something/test` instead of `localhost:3000/something/test`. The href just gets appended to the current path `/foo`

Removing the dynamic segment in the href (now being `href={'/something'}`) from the Link, gets me to `localhost:3000/something`.

Should I use `useRouter` in this instance or is there some way to do it with Link?

```
#in /foo/[test1]#

export default function Home(){
    return(
       <Link href={`/something/test`}> Click me</Link> // should get me to localhost:3000/something test
    );
}

# in /something/[test2]
export default function Page(){

    const { query } = useRouter();

    return(
       <div>
          {query.test2}
       </div>
    );
}
```

Clicking on the Link gets me to `localhost:3000/foo/something/test` which is not a defined route.

Comment: Would you mind writing an example page? Is hard to tell what are you doing wrong if not. Also, in the second paragraph, both URLs look the same.

Comment: Hey @Eloi, is it clear now?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to reproduce the behaviour of your Link, it works as intended for me.

Comment: The code you have should behave as expected. Could you also show us your `next.config.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Link. All you need to do is add `../` to href. Next treats this like any terminal. So to get `localhost:3000` you could do `href = {"../../something/test"}`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you through where you want to.

```
export default function Home(){
    const pathname = "something/test"
    return(
       <Link href={"/" + pathname}> Click me</Link> // should get me to localhost:3000/something test
    );
}
```